# Extract Route Statistics in Camel

Tags: java, apache-camel

On JConsole, We can see following route Statistics.

1. Minimum / Maximum / Mean Processing Time
2. First / last Message completion Time
3. Number of messages failed or re-delivered.
4. Total number of transaction processed

**Requirement**: I need to show above data on web page.
Below is my code:

```
public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

CamelContext context = exchange.getContext();
List<Route> routeObj = context.getRoutes();
for (Route routeId : routeObj) {
    boolean started = context.getRouteStatus(strRouteId).isStarted();
    boolean stopped = context.getRouteStatus(strRouteId).isStopped();
    boolean suspended = context.getRouteStatus(strRouteId).isSuspended();
    // TODO: find min/max/mean processing time, first/last message
    // completion time, etc.
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Please suggest me how to get min/max/mean processing time, first/last message completion time, etc.

Comment: These information are exposed using JMX. Have you tried using JMX?

Comment: I am not getting how to use JMX is above code. I would appreciate if you could give me some piece of code. Thanks

Comment: I can give you something even better than some piece of code. Here is the [official JMX tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/) and the [Apache Camel JMX Documentation](http://camel.apache.org/camel-jmx.html#CamelJMX-CamelJMX) ;)

Comment: JMX tutorial says about defining creating a custom MBean and Notification related. In one of the link, they just say how to configure JMX such that it will gather all statistics at route level. In my requirement, Camel is running. It has some routes which are started. In above code, I have to find statistics for each route. Through context I can get MBeanServer. But after that there is no way to get statistics for the specific route. Please help me out.

Comment: I updated my answer, plz check it out :) I did what you are attempting before, but I'm sorry I can't find any reference regarding the PublishEventNotifier other than the javadoc

Answer (score 1):

See for example the Camel Karaf commands that can dump statistics too. They use the JMX API to do that.

An example is the context-info command: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/platforms/karaf/commands/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/karaf/commands/ContextInfo.java

Comment: Another alternative is to use jolokia which exposes an REST api for JMX, and makes it much easier for web developers to access this data, such as what we have done in the hawtio web console - http://hawt.io/

Answer (score 0):

Apache camel exposes these information using JMX.

A good starting point is the [official JMX tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/) and the [Apache Camel JMX Documentation](http://camel.apache.org/camel-jmx.html#CamelJMX-CamelJMX)

You can actually **calculate** the info you require, using `org.apache.camel.management.PublishEventNotifier`

One type of events will get notified of is concerning camel exchanges (like completion, failure...) of each route. The only piece of information you need after that is the processing time of a this exchange (last exchange) which is obtainable using JMX (LastProcessingTime).

Once you have the exchanges processing time for each route, all the information you require can be calculated in real-time.